# File upload handling and buffering internals with Jersey API

Tags: java, http, servlets, file-upload, jersey

How does Jersey handle receiving files from a client (e.g. web application)?

I've looked around for a longer while and cannot seem to get the answers I need.

Let's say that I have an exposed Jersey endpoint that consumes a multipart data form with a file that looks pretty much like this:

```
@POST
public Response upload(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream inputStream,
                       @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetails { ... }
```

I've noticed that if I try to upload the file, the endpoint is not called until the uploading is finished. Does Jersey attempt to read and buffer (memory? disk?) an entire file before handling it for further processing? Does it mean that the inputStream source and size is already known when the processing of endpoint logic starts (because it was already read)?

And finally, is it possible to handle it in a "as comes" manner, without waiting with further actions for whole file to be uploaded first?